# Setting static constant value (not by preprocessor) at compile time

Tags: c++, c++11, static, compilation

just short question.
I can define preprocessor variables at compile time, using `-D` flag for `g++`. But is there a way to set value of normal constant variable this way?

I want to avoid preprocessor. I don't see any reason, why this couldn't be possible.

Comment: Thats exactly what the preprocessor is used for (and one of the few case where it should be used)...

Comment: I don't understand your question. You want to avoid the preprocessor, but initialize a `const` variable in some way that can be varied at compile time?

Comment: @Praetorian Yes, so I would be able to use this variables in type-safe and stuff c++ functions, not in preprocessor macros.

Comment: By "compile time" do you mean "as a command line parameter to the compiler"?

Comment: @KrzysztofStanisławek Ok, then initialize a `const` global variable with a value that you obtain via a preprocessor symbol.

Answer (score 7):

Well, you cannot define a variable from a compiler switch. You can fake it though:

```
const int my_cli_defined_variable = MY_CLI_DEFINED_VARIABLE
#undef MY_CLI_DEFINED_VARIABLE
```

and then:

```
g++ -DMY_CLI_DEFINED_VARIABLE=5 …
```

The second line will make sure that the preprocessor macro won't be used by accident by your real code, because the macro won't exist anymore. So, the only way to use this CLI-defined variable will be in a type-safe way through the const variable.

A full example that takes care of the situation when the macro is not defined:

```
const int my_cli_defined_variable = 
#ifdef MY_CLI_DEFINED_VARIABLE
    MY_CLI_DEFINED_VARIABLE;
#undef MY_CLI_DEFINED_VARIABLE
#else
    42;
#endif
```

Comment: You could even give it a default value via `#ifndef`.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

#if defined MYCONST_VAL
static const int MYCONST = MYCONST_VAL;
#else
static const int MYCONST = 3;
#endif

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::cout << MYCONST << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This works:

```
$ clang++ preproc.cc 
$ ./a.out 
3
$ clang++ -D MYCONST_VAL=77 preproc.cc 
$ ./a.out 
77
```

It's somewhat ugly though. I wouldn't recommend doing this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only a small set of values (or if you don't mind having a ton of small files), you can write a set of header files containing the variable definition with appropriate initializer, and then include the wanted one using the `-include` option.

However note that when including files, no matter whether using `#include` in the source code or using the `-include` option of g++, you also use the preprocessor, so you'll not be able to avoid that.

For example, you might have a header file `8bit.h` containing the line

```
int const bit_size = 8;
```

and another header file `16bit.h` containing the line

```
int const bit_size = 16;
```

and then compile your source with

```
g++ foo.cc -include 8bit.h
```